# How to change the class name of links based on routing in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have some links,here I need to change the class name of the links based on routing.Suppose I am in home page the class of anchor tag will be active,again suppose I route to steps1,my steps1 link should be active and class name of home link should be changed to complete,again if I route to steps2,my steps2 link should be active and and class name of steps1 link should be complete..so on
Here is the code below,I am totally new to angular

### steps.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-steps',
  templateUrl: './steps.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './steps.component.css' ]
})
export class StepsComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}


}
```

### steps.component.html

```
<div>
<a class="active" [routerLink] = "['/project']">Home</a>
<a class="disabled" [routerLink] = "['/project/steps1']">Steps1</a>
<a class="disabled" [routerLink] = "['/project/steps2']">Steps2</a>
<a class="disabled" [routerLink] = "['/project/steps3']">Steps3</a>
</div>
```

### steps.component.css

```
.active{color:red}
.complete{color:green}
.disabled{color:yellow}
```

Comment: It should help you https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: This we need to do in angular may be need to use [ngClass] for changing based on route condition

Comment: To detect if a link is `active` you can use `RouterLinkActive` https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: I am not getting how to use here and I need to make previous routes complete also